# Webapplication fails to load content when authenticated using windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, iis-express

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC webapplication currently running on IIS Express (for development).

The webapplication has two pages

- Computer
- Department

General authentication settings in `web.config`

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

The `DeparmentController` enforces authentication using the authorize attribute:
`[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Administrators")]`

When visiting the computer page unauthorized, all content loads fine.

[image: content load success]

When visiting the department page, I'm prompted to enter my credentials. The authentication works as expected, but I get '500 Internal Server Error' on css, js and ico files.

[image: content load error]

During my research, I only found the exact same problem the other way around. Where the static files where not loaded for unauthorized users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement windows authorization within iis as well,  also does your user have permission to the directories that the page is displaying?

Comment: Isn't this enabled by default in IIS Express? Authenitication works. Only loading of static content gives errors. Admin user should have access to all files because of web.config

Comment: Missed the bit on iisexpress

Comment: Could the following help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499220/why-is-iis-express-returning-http-500-errors-loading-javascript-and-css

Comment: I deleted the `.vs` folder as well as the `IISExpress` folder under Documents and restarted Visual Studio -> Did **not** solve the problem.